# Verifying condition in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I need a function that checks a condition on a list.

For example:

```
countP :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Int
```

with the input:

```
countP [1,-2,0,-1,5] (>0)
```

should return 2, because there are two numbers greater than zero.

Here's what i've done so far:

```
countP :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Int
countP [] _ = []
countP (x:xs) condition = if condition x then 1:countP xs condition else countP xs condition
```

It's returning [1,1] instead of the number two. It must be recursive.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Do you insist on doing it by hand? Because you can use [filter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) and [length](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Prelude.html#v:length).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the result, like this

```
countP :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Int
countP [] _ = 0
countP (x:xs) condition = (if condition x then 1 else 0) + (countP xs condition)
```

Whenever `condition x` evaluates to True, we use `1` otherwise `0` and we recursively call `countP` and add them.

So, when you invoke it like this

```
countP [1, -2, 0, -1, 5] (>0)
```

it will be evaluated *recursively*, like this

```
(if (> 0) 1 then 1 else 0) + (countP [-2, 0, -1, 5] (> 0))
1 + (countP [-2, 0, -1, 5] (> 0))
1 + (if (> 0) -1 then 1 else 0) + (countP [0, -1, 5] (> 0))
1 + 0 + (countP [0, -1, 5] (> 0))
1 + 0 + 0 + (countP [-1, 5] (> 0))
1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + (countP [5] (> 0))
1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + (countP [] (> 0))
1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 = 2
```

`(countP [] (> 0))` is evaluated to be `0` because of our *base condition* of our recursive function `countP [] _ = 0`. It means that no matter what the second parameter is, if the first parameter is an empty list, then return 0.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be over thinking this. You can use some of the Prelude provided functions and compose them to produce the result:

```
length $ filter (>0) [1,-2,0,-1,5]
```

`length` will take a list and tell you how long it is.
`filter` takes a predicate and tells you how many elements in a provided list match that predicate.
So if you get the `length` of the `filter`ed list, you are set.

```
countP xs f = length $ filter f xs
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function specifically for counting the number of things in a list, and it's called `length`.  You could do something like

```
countP' [] _ = []
countP' (x:xs) condition = if condition x then 1 : countP' xs condition else countP' xs condition

countP xs condition = length (countP' xs condition)
```

However, this takes two functions and it does extra work.  Instead you could work directly with `Int`s instead of `[Int]`s:

```
countP :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> Int
countP [] _ = 0
countP (x:xs) condition = ...
```

I'll still let you fill in the blanks here, know that you are not very far from the correct solution with what you already have.

However, if I were going to implement this code in a project, I would simply reach for `length` and `filter`:

```
countP xs condition = length (filter condition xs)
```

This is what I would call the idiomatic definition (up to argument order).